# Get max and min values along with all values and multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, max

I have this query which works very good

```
  SELECT cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown 
  FROM chat_messages cm 
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cm.date_edited,'$now') < 10 GROUP BY cm.id
```

Which gives me the entries which are edited in less then 10 seconds.

But along with that im trying to get also the `max(voteup)` and `min(votedown)`

But dont affect the first entries of the first query . How can i combine then to get all entries i need ?

Example:

if im getting 3 newly updates entries . i want to get them those 3 plus the max of voteup and votedown .

Example:

```
    id   edited  date_edited          voteup    votedown
    37      0      2016-03-05 22:13:03    5         0
    38      0      2016-04-02 11:15:00    3         7
    39      0      2016-03-05 22:10:06    10        6
    40      0      2016-03-20 21:40:06    5         0
    41      1      2016-04-20 22:28:59    5         0
    42      1      2016-03-20 21:59:15    0         20
    43      1      2016-04-21 22:20:25    8         0     <---- this new updated
```

My wished result is

```
    id   edited  date_edited         voteup  votedown  maxup  maxdown
    39      0      2016-03-05 22:10:06    10        6    10     NULL
    42      1      2016-03-20 21:59:15    0         20   NUll   20
    43      1      2016-04-21 22:20:25    8         0    NULL   NULL
```

My `$now` time is `2016-04-21 22:20:20`

explanation:

```
   -id 39 is having maxup vote i want get it

   -id 42  is having maxdown i want get it

   -id 43 is newly updated in that period of 10 seconds.
```

so i general i want get new updated entries pls the max up  and down .

**if many max voteup values are same then just choose one which have min votedown**

Any solution to that pls ?

Here **[my sqlfiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc1d4d)**

**Edit:** oh sorry i meant id . now wish my question is clear like [image]

Comment: your sql fiddle doesn't have an `id` field, with which you are using in the `GROUP BY` clause in your working statement above.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII edted , sorry i meant id :)

Comment: you still have a `cm.userid` in the select statement above ;)

Comment: Jeeeeeeeeeff stop now hahaha, edited

Comment: The original query has no need for a `GROUP BY`, there are no aggregate functions. You need to calculate your MIN, MAX values in a subquery and JOIN that back to the table.

Comment: What about when there are multiple records with the max up or down value? (There is the idea that on a 1-10 scale, people tend to rate things 1 or 10).

Comment: @Uueerdo if many max voteup values are same then just choose one which have   min votedown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will want to use a `UNION` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown 
        , voteup as maxup, null AS maxdown
    from chat_messages cm
    ORDER BY voteup DESC, votedown
    LIMIT 1
) a
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    select cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown 
        , null as maxup, votedown AS maxdown
    from chat_messages cm
    ORDER BY votedown DESC, voteup
    LIMIT 1
) b
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown 
        , null as maxup, null AS maxdown
  from chat_messages cm
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cm.date_edited,'2016-04-21 22:20:20') < 10
) c
```

note that I used `'2016-04-21 22:20:20'`, but you will want to substitute the `$now` back in

Comment: That will explode, or have weird behavior, if the fields in `chat_messages`  are not defined in the order you selected them in the last part. And technically you're still not calculating the max and min, just fetching the rows they are found in.

Comment: im not calculating no , im fetching, i didnt come yet to the right result from your answer .

Comment: where to check and put NULL or a value ?

Comment: thanks **@Uueerdo**, this will retrieve cols in same order. sorry **@scooter**, I left off `DESC`

Comment: Actually, other than my concern for the cost of the `ORDER BY` clauses, this is very easily tweaked to get what you want. Just add the following to the selected fields lists: `voteup as maxup, null AS maxdown` to the first, `null as maxup, votedown as maxdown` to the second, and `null, null` to the end of the third.

Comment: you see my edited answer? if there are many same max values :) ?

Comment: **@scooter**, yes I saw your edited question, so I edited my answer with secondary sort.

Comment: **@Uueerdo**, I didn't follow your comment on `maxup` and `maxdown` usage. care to post an answer, or suggest edits to mine?

Comment: **@Uueerdo**, ah yes, I understand what you're saying now. I'd missed that in the question. thanks

Comment: this actually gives right result i have tested it ., but im just waiting if there is much shorter and cleaner and faster query , like the answer above is shorter with no union just normal select. [your fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dafb/1)

Comment: @ScooterDaraf If you only want one each of the maxdown and maxup records, this is probably the simplest way to go.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf Otherwise you need a "max" subquery inside a "min" subquery inside a "first" subquery for voteup, and another set like that for votedown, and then have those joined to the original table.

Comment: Ok i guess im going with your query like they said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868530/is-it-better-do-to-a-union-in-sql-or-separate-queries-and-then-use-php-array-mer) , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use user-defined variables to track your maximums and then outer query the rows that match your rules.

```
SELECT id,edited,date_edited,voteup,votedown,
       IF(voteup=@maxvoteup,voteup,NULL) as maxvoteup,
       IF(votedown=@maxvotedown,votedown,NULL) as maxvotedown
FROM (SELECT cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,
       @maxvoteup := GREATEST(@maxvoteup,cm.voteup) as maxvoteup,
       @maxvotedown := GREATEST(@maxvotedown,cm.votedown) as maxvotedown
      FROM chat_messages cm,(SELECT @maxvoteup:=0,@maxvotedown:=0)initial
     )T
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_edited,'2016-04-21 22:20:25') < 10
   OR voteup = @maxvoteup
   OR votedown = @maxvotedown
ORDER BY id ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043ae/10)

Here's another query that is much more CRAZY..but it works ..

for maxupvote row, it'll find row that has maxupvote and minimum down vote, if more than 1 row exists (in a tie) it'll grab the row with latest/largest id.
for maxdownvote row, it'll find row that has maxdownvote and minimum up vote,
if more than 1 row exists (in a tie) it'll grab the row with latest/largest id.

```
SELECT id,edited,date_edited,voteup,votedown,
       IF(voteup=@maxvoteup,voteup,NULL) as maxvoteup,
       IF(votedown=@maxvotedown,votedown,NULL) as maxvotedown
FROM (SELECT cm.id ,cm.edited,cm.date_edited,cm.voteup,cm.votedown,
       @minvotedown :=
            (CASE WHEN cm.voteup > @maxvoteup OR (cm.voteup = @maxvoteup AND cm.votedown < @minvotedown)
                  THEN cm.votedown
                  ELSE @minvotedown
            END),
       @minvoteup :=
            (CASE WHEN cm.votedown > @maxvotedown OR (cm.votedown = @maxvotedown AND cm.voteup < @minvoteup)
                  THEN cm.voteup
                  ELSE @minvoteup
            END),
       @maxvoteup := GREATEST(@maxvoteup,cm.voteup) as maxvoteup,
       @maxvotedown := GREATEST(@maxvotedown,cm.votedown) as maxvotedown,
       @maxvoteupid :=
             (CASE WHEN cm.voteup = @maxvoteup AND cm.votedown = @minvotedown 
              THEN cm.id
              ELSE @maxvoteupid
              END),
       @maxvotedownid :=
             (CASE WHEN cm.votedown = @maxvotedown AND cm.voteup = @minvoteup
              THEN cm.id
              ELSE @maxvotedownid
              END)
      FROM chat_messages cm,(SELECT @maxvoteup:=0,@maxvotedown:=0,@minvoteup:=0,@minvotedown:=0,@maxvoteupid:=0,@maxvotedownid:=0)initial
      ORDER BY cm.id ASC
     )T
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_edited,'2016-04-21 22:20:25') < 10
   OR id = @maxvoteupid
   OR id = @maxvotedownid
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5df48/2)

I call it CRAZY because it is...if i was doing this. I would just run 3 separate queries

1 query to return one row with `order by upvote DESC, downvote ASC, id DESC` limit 1

1 query to return one row with `order by downvote DESC, upvote ASC, id DESC` limit 1

1 query to return one row that's within the last 10 seconds `order by id DESC`
this way it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: I am fairly certain that query will have very unpredictable results. I am a big fan of session variables, but they have a bad reputation because they do not behave predictably when used across clauses.

Comment: look that [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25004/1) doesnt give one max with less downvote , it should give id 41,42,43

Comment: there's something strange with the fiddle, because I ran this statement against my local db and got the expected results.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII his fiddle is right but when i edited two same maxvalues it didnt give right result, i gave him fiddle example in my comment

Comment: @JeffPuckettII look this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0508a/1) your query gives right result , but not Tins query. if it gives right result then you have to reinstall your local db :)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do when there is a tie between maximums

Comment: OK, I see now the nesting _probably_ will make the clause crossing safe, however I would think about renaming the inner `max` aliases to `tmp` or something as they will have intermediate values (you've basically constructed a goldberg machine to reproduce the behavior of the standard MAX function).

Comment: what if you have rows that have equal maxvote and minvote which one do you show? all of them or just one with smallest id or largest id....these are to be determined in order to change the query to give you what you want

Comment: i can't rename the inner maxes because those are the values i am looking at the outer query when everything is done.

Comment: I cant have new column with max voteup because i have to check with second query if its max or not.

Comment: It would be better if we can  group by `maxvoteup` to get just one maxvoteup or maxvotedown

Comment: @TinTran you do not use the inner max **fields** outside of the inner query, only the max session variables. _If you used those fields, the query would not work_

Comment: there i just updated my answer with a CRAZY query..check it out :D

Comment: Your CRAZY query is really crazy :) . But it works . however i have little question? is better to run 3 queries as you mentioned then one query for example your first query not the crazy one. because i thought 3 queries will be much ping to database even if i call the database every 10 seconds it will be pinged 3 times each 10 seconds. what you suggest pls thanks .

Comment: well i don't know about performance hits. but i was taught that simple queries are preferred over complex queries, plus you get a trade off as your code is easier to maintain, you have 3 very simple queries.